# pfg conditional addition of a number

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I have coordinates stored in `\xCoor` and `\yCoor`, and and converting these into polar coordinates to express on paper. I'm wanting this done automatically, and have been able to define:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angleValue}{ atan( \yCoor / \xCoor ) }
```

Which works well, and returns the answer expected if this was from a calculator. However, I want the properly defined angle with respect to the x-axis rather than this answer. Subsequently, I would like to conditionally add values of 0, 180, or 360 to this value depending based on the quadrant the coordinate is in, which can be figured out based on the values of `\xCoor`and `\yCoor`.

I've taken a look at at using an `\ifthenelse{<condition>}{<if true>}{<if false>}`, but this is not accepted by the code (does not appear that the ifthenelse works well inside a calculation). I understand that `\ifnum` requires integer values, which my coordinate values are definitely not.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is a sample case:
Consider the coordinate (-3.49, 2) then `-29.82` is stored in `\angleValue`, but this really should be `150.18` degrees. Subsequently, I need to add 180 degrees to the output to get the correct value to print for the angle.

Here is a different sample case:
Consider the coordinate (3.49, -2) then `-29.82` is stored in `\angleValue`, but this really should be `330.18` degrees. Subsequently, I need to add 360 degrees to the output to get the correct value to print for the angle.

So, it comes down to conditionally adding values depending on the sign of `\xCoor` and `\yCoor`

Comment: can you include a sample case? I didn't exactly understand the requirement

Comment: I added 2 examples. Please let me know if there is any further clarification that might be needed. If you can show me how to conditionally add numbers, I can take care of the logic for what numbers to add under the needed conditions, just cannot figure out the way to implement the conditional addition.

Comment: you can use atan2

Comment: Yes programmers usually call it `atan2` which is the quadrant preserving version of `atan`

Comment: That is a lot easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if `\xcoord` and `\ycoord` will always be pure numbers. If they are you can use this:

edit: ah sorry, naturally you can have decimal numbers as coordinates. Well, assuming then that `\xcoord` and `\ycoord` are always unitless:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=.2cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (-3,0) --(3,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\foreach \xCoor/\yCoor in{3/3,2.5/4.5,3/-3,2.5/-4.5,
                         -3/-3,-2.5/-4.5,-3/3,-2.5/4.5}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angleValue}{ atan( \xCoor/-\yCoor ) + 
                               \ifdim\yCoor pt<0pt 270\else 90\fi}

\draw (0,0) -- (\xCoor,\yCoor)node[right, color=red]{\angleValue};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternative using an extra-package for some expandable handling of decimal numbers (among others).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xintfrac}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (-3,0) --(3,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\foreach \xCoor/\yCoor in{3/3,2.5/4.5,3/-3,2.5/-4.5,
                         -3/-3,-2.5/-4.5,-3/3,-2.5/4.5}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angleValue}{\xintifSgn {\yCoor}
   {atan( -\xCoor/\yCoor ) + 270}% negative y coord
   {\xintifSgn{\xCoor}{180}{\ORIGINNOANGLE}{0}}% zero y
   {atan( -\xCoor/\yCoor ) + 90}% positive y
}

\draw (0,0) -- (\xCoor,\yCoor)node[right, color=red]{\angleValue};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: If you don't want the rotation introduced from this solution, you can use (based on what you gave as an answer) `\pgfmathsetmacro{\angleValue}{ atan2( \yCoor , \xCoor ) + \ifdim\yCoor pt<0pt 360 \else 0\fi}` instead, but your answer works as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `atan2` will indeed handle better cases of vanishing `yCoor`... (I guess so, I shamefully admit not being familiar with TikZ powerful syntax.) What about `atan2(\yCoor, \xCoor) mod 360` recommended by @percusse ? (I don't know the TikZ syntax for that I hope this is the way to write it)

Comment: That returns a lot of 0 angles for me, so it doesn't yield the same result. I think that function looks at the modulus, which would take the answer and divide by 360, returning the remainder.... but then I would expect a different value out, so I may be mistaken about that function, but either way doesn't yield the expected or desired answer in the end.

Comment: perhaps it does not handle well fractional input? well, I don't know. Glad my somewhat eccentric answer is of any use ;-)

Answer (score 3):

with atan2 ([atan 2 (wikipédia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (-3,0) --(3,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\foreach \xCoor/\yCoor in{3/3,3/-3,-3/-3,-3/3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angleValue}{ atan2( \yCoor,\xCoor ) }

\draw (0,0) -- (\xCoor,\yCoor)node[right]{\angleValue};
}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would ideally like to only have positive values. So, could you modify it such that if the value is negative, it adds 360 to the answer? This would ensure only positive values are given while still representing the angle needed.

Comment: @Jeremie Use mod function for that.

Comment: @Jeremie `180+atan2(-x,-y)`. Or perhaps `180+atan2(-y,-x)` from what I see here arguments of `atan2` are in reverse order.

Comment: viz my comment, unfortunately `atan2` gets values from `-180` excluded to `+180` included. Hence this would go from `0` excluded to `360` included, which possibly is not naively expected. Seems `mod` is way to go because of that.